# Kafka Connect with Debezium

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, cdc, debezium

I have setup the environment with `Postgresql` database , used [debezium](/questions/tagged/debezium) connector with Kafka Connect and Kafka. There are multiple instances(3) of Kafka running, and it is configured with Zookeeper (3).The connections in the entire pipeline is working , but as per the documentation of Debezium, there are no topics created automatically as per the tables in the database. Such as if is table A and table B inside some schema, I assume the 2 topics created implicitly in Kafka. The status of the connector and task is `RUNNING`, below mentioned are the configuration that I have done for the connector ,

```
{
   "name": "geo-connector",
   "config": {
    "connector.class":     "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": <dbHostName>,
    "database.port": <dbPort>,
    "database.user": <dbUser>,
    "database.password":<dbPassword> ,
    "database.dbname" : <dbName>,
    "database.server.name": <logicalName>,
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":<>,
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
    "plugin.name":"wal2json",
    "config.storage.replication.factor": "3",
    "offset.storage.replication.factor" : "3",
    "auto.create.topics.enable" : "true",
    "snapshot.mode" : "always"
  }
}
```

The error that I see in the Connect logs are as ,

```
2018-08-09 15:28:50,409 - DEBUG [KafkaBasedLog Work Thread - kconnect-offsets:Fetcher@199] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=1] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(), toForget=(), implied=(kconnect-offsets-10, kconnect-offsets-4, kconnect-offsets-16, kconnect-offsets-7, kconnect-offsets-19, kconnect-offsets-13, kconnect-offsets-22, kconnect-offsets-1)) to broker kafka-02.hotel02.pro06.eu.idealo.com:9092 (id: 2002 rack: pro06)
2018-08-09 15:28:50,465 - DEBUG [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-6:NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater@927] - [Producer clientId=producer-6] Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=dbserver1.public.spatial_ref_sys) to node kafka-01.hotel02.pro05.eu.idealo.com:9092 (id: 2004 rack: pro05)
2018-08-09 15:28:50,467 - WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-6:NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater@882] - [Producer clientId=producer-6] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 23856 : {dbserver1.public.spatial_ref_sys=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
2018-08-09 15:28:50,467 - DEBUG [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-6:Metadata@270] - Updated cluster metadata version 23852 to Cluster(id = BwqlZApfT-ygzWr_wPcdng, nodes = [kafka-03.hotel02.pro05.eu.idealo.com:9092 (id: 2003 rack: pro05), kafka-01.hotel02.pro05.eu.idealo.com:9092 (id: 2004 rack: pro05), kafka-02.hotel02.pro06.eu.idealo.com:9092 (id: 2002 rack: pro06)], partitions = [])
```

Comment: Kafka won't automatically create topics if it's explicitly disabled in the property file

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 , the issue was , since aut0.create.topics was disabled in kafka configurations therefore no topics with table name was reflected as kafka topics and when the kafka was hit to get metadata for the topic , it throws an error that UNKNOWN _TOPIC_OR_PARTITION. Resolved it by enabling it

Answer (score 0):

The message you see in logs is warning, not an error. Could you please try `kafka-topics.sh` utility to list the topics available?